# (Python3) How do you get the time stamp of a remote file in python (i.e. a web link)?

Tags: python, timestamp

I have already seen the examples on here of using python's os library to get a ***local*** file's time stamp in python by passing it the local path (i.e. /var/www/html/etc.../filename.txt), but when I try to pass getmtime a link, it cannot process it.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
import os
print(os.path.getmtime('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1474439/000169655519000022/xslF345X03/wf-form4_156772823294389.xml'))
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1474439/000169655519000022/xslF345X03/wf-form4_156772823294389.xml'
```

I know that this link exists.

So it obviously doesn't like me passing it a link.  Is there another function that you use to pass links, to get the last modification time of a remote file?

Comment: Do you control the remote file and for what purpose do you want the last modified time? A `HEAD` request is generally used for getting metadata about a request/resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An URL is not necessarily a file. You can ask the remote server to tell you about the link, and the remote server may provide a `Last-Modified` header, or may not, at the remote server's discretion. It could also lie, if so instructed. In order to do this, you would need to make a HTTP request; the easiest way to do it from Python is the nice `requests` library.

```
import requests
import dateutil.parser

response = requests.head(url)
last_modified = response.headers.get('Last-Modified')
if last_modified:
    last_modified = dateutil.parser.parse(last_modified)
```